# Accessing props using variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to use variable names to access state data in props. Here's what I've tried so far which hasn't worked.

I have the following items that I want to access in my props:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        redCar: state.cars.redCar,
        blueCar: state.cars.blueCar
    }
}
```

Both red and blue cars are objects that look like this:

```
{
   id: "red-car",
   year: 2017,
   make: "Infiniti",
   model: "QX 80"
}
{
   id: "blue-car",
   year: 2018,
   make: "RAM",
   model: "1500"
}
```

I'm trying to access make and model using variables as below which is not working. I'm getting "undefined":

```
handleChange(car, propertyName, value) {

   const currentValue = this.props[car][propertyName];
}
```

How do I access my props using variable names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        redCar: state.cars.redCar,
        blueCar: state.cars.blueCar
    }
}
```

In this function you are specifying that you will have keys on your props called `redCar` and `blueCar`.

```
handleChange(car, propertyName, value) {

   const currentValue = this.props["car"]["propertyName"];
}
```

Here you are attempting to use bracket notation to access the property. Bracket notation only works if the string passed in to the brackets, is spelled exactly the same as the name of the key, which in your case it isn't.  The property could be either `redCar` or `blueCar`, but its isn't `"car"`.

Assuming that the `car` argument passed in to the `handleChange` function could have the value of either `redCar` or `blueCar` you can rewrite your code like this,

```
handleChange(car, propertyName, value) {

   const currentValue = this.props[car][propertyName];
}
```

[Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: Yup! The names were not matching exactly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is the values of `car` variable are `redCar` and `blueCar` ?

then you can do :

```
handleChange(car, propertyName, value) {
  const currentValue = this.props[car][propertyName];
}
```